# How to create a basic listview in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to create a basic `list view` or `scroll view` in my scene in the game development engine, Unity.

- I just beginning to learn Unity.
- I have attempted to create a `list view` without success.
- I have a set of strings which I need to display like a `list view` or `scroll view`.
- One below the other, I have entered the strings in to a `List<string>` now.

Now what am doing is set the string to display directly with the new line character, `\n`.

I also tried adding the strings to the content of `scroll view` in unity, but I have not managed to get it working.

Can anyone please provide a reference?

Comment: Maybe you could add your accompanying code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "easiest" and most elegant way I can think about is using a [Vertical Layout Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html)

1. Add a new empty gameobject under your canvas
2. Set the desired dimensions using the `RectTransform` component
3. Attach the "Vertical Layout Group" component
4. In your code, for each string in your list :

   - Create a new GameObject :
   - Attach a text component to it
   - Fill the `text` attribute with your string
   - Set the parent of the transform to be the first empty gameobject in 1st step

Here is a piece of code **I haven't tested** :

```
// Drag & Drop the vertical layout group here
public UnityEngine.UI.VerticalLayoutGroup verticalLayoutGroup ;

// ... In your function
RectTransform parent = verticalLayoutGroup.GetComponent<RectTransform>() ;
for( int index = 0 ; index < stringList.Count ; ++index )
{
     GameObject g = new GameObject( stringList[index] ) ;
     UnityEngine.UI.Text t = g.AddComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
     t.addComponent<RectTransform>().setParent( parent ) ;
     t.text = stringList[index] ;
}
```

If you need more customization, you can instantiate a prefab instead of manually create the texts gameobjects.